# MySQL Structure for large array

Tags: mysql

I have a grid of numbers 100*100 = 10000, each number is just a very small int ( it has a value from 0 to 9).

I need to store every number to a MySQL database, but I don't know how best to approach this.

Do I have to do a table with 10000 columns? Or do I just do 2 columns and in the second one store all the data like "159875621511884...... until I have the 10000 numbers and then separate each number for its retrieval? What is the best way to do it?

I will use C# to do this, or maybe C# => php => mySQL.

Comment: What have you tried? Did it work? In my opinion, this depends on how you plan to use it. When you get a row from the database, what do you expect it to contain? If you want {row, column, value}, then store {row, column, value}. If you want {value, value, value, value...} then store {value, value, value, value...}

Comment: hi, thanks for your fast comment. I havent tried anything yet, im just triyng to figure it out how im going to do it

Comment: I really just want to know which is the best approach for doing this

Comment: Your question is too broad and makes little sense. To simplify what I understood it sounds like you are asking "How do I store numbers in a database?". What are you doing with the numbers? Are you just storing 10000 single digit numbers 1-9? How are you accessing and using the numbers? We need to understand your use case to suggest something....

Comment: yes im sorry, you are right. the problem is that i was reading some forums and i saw that you cant have 10000 columns in a MySQL server, so i was wondering how can i store 10000 separated numbers in mysql ( i said i am very new to SQL so i dont have any idea how to do this), and how can i retrive them in the most "easy" way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're representing a grid, use the grid row and column as the primary key of the table.

```
CREATE TABLE grid (
    row INT(3),
    col INT(3),
    value INT(1),
    PRIMARY KEY (row, col)
);
```

You can then get a specific cell with:

```
SELECT value FROM grid WHERE row = 9 AND col = 20;
```

and get all the cells in a row with:

```
SELECT col, value FROM grid WHERE row = 15 ORDER BY col;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, just one question (maybe a very bad question) how do i insert the values?

Comment: `INSERT INTO grid VALUES (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 8), (0, 2, 5), ...`

Comment: something else, i read that you can only have 4096 columns in a table, isnt that going to be a problem?

Comment: No problem, we only have 3 columns.

Comment: I think you need to review basics of databases to understand what a column is.

Comment: What an intelligent (and usefull) answer to a very broad question! +1